# How to move variables matched to column A in column B to another row with the same variable as column A with an empty column B?

Tags: r

I have a dataset in the following general form

```
Subject. Target.  Valence
1.       annoy.    n
1.       beauty.   p
1.       shirt.    o
1.       succeed.  p
.
.
.
2.       beauty
2.       annoy
2.       succeed
```

Basically we have data from 1600 different people on a large number of target words each. This dataset only has the valence for the first subject but the valence is not inputted for the rest of the participants. The order of the target words is different for each person. What I am trying to do is find in my dataset each time the target word is found and copy the valence from subject 1 and move the valence letter everywhere that word is found in the document.

Ultimately, it should look something like this:

```
Subject. Target.  Valence
1.       annoy.    n
1.       beauty.   p
1.       shirt.    o
1.       succeed.  p
.
.
.
2.       beauty.   p
2.       annoy.    n
2.       succeed.  p
```

I ideally want to complete this in R but am also somewhat familiar with MATLAB. There are over 1000 words for each participant, so directly searching for each word is not reasonable but the only way I have figured out how to make this work.

Thank you in advance. I am a beginner in R, so I apologize if the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` to get the row index where the 'Target' from 'Subject' 1 matches with the other Subjects and then assign it to the 'Valence' column based on the index

```
i1 <- df1$Subject != 1
df1$Valence[i1] <- with(df1, 
       Valence[match(Target[i1], Target[!i1])])
df1
#  Subject  Target Valence
#1       1   annoy       n
#2       1  beauty       p
#3       1   shirt       o
#4       1 succeed       p
#5       2  beauty       p
#6       2   annoy       n
#7       2 succeed       p
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Target = c("annoy", 
"beauty", "shirt", "succeed", "beauty", "annoy", "succeed"), 
    Valence = c("n", "p", "o", "p", NA, NA, NA)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 2):

That previous suggestion has the parentheses in the wrong place. It should read:

```
i1 <- df1$Subject != 1
df1$Valence[i1] <- with(df1, 
       Valence[match(Target[i1], Target[!i1])])
```

Match is your best bet here.